# Porque es tan grande mi archivo de base de datos en mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una consulta con el tamaño de la base de datos en mongoDB.
Copié una tabla de Postgres de 3 millones de registros a mongoDB.

La tabla en Postgres pesa 400Mb.
La coleccion en mongoDB pesa 1.6Gb

Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal o simplemente en mongoDB es mas caro guardar datos ?

Gracias

Comment: No veo de mucha ayuda cuando son millones de datos, ya que por lo que veo los títulos se repiten y eso genera que crezca el tamaño de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Ocurre porque MongoDB usa pre-alocación de espacio para cada uno de los archivos y mantiene registros (*journals*) de la historia de uso de los archivos.

Hay una [buena respuesta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533419/why-my-mongodb-filesize-is-much-bigger-than-storagesize-in-db-stats) y traduzco solo un resumen de como funciona en MongoDB 3 aqui abajo. La respuesta original proviene de la información en el [FAQ de MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/)

**Pre-alocación de archivos**

MongoDB trata de evitar fragmentación en tu disco duro pre-alocando un tamaño a cada archivo. Por esto el tamaño en tu disco duro puede ser mayor al tamaño que de verdad esta en uso por tus datos.

Esto es probablemente la mayor causa de la diferencia que encuentras. La opción `storage.mmapv1.smallFiles` te permite reducir el tamaño de estos archivos.

**El registro oplog.rs**

Si el mongod que estas usando es miembro de un set de replicas, la carpeta de datos incluye un archivo `oplog.rs`. Aqui hay un *capped collection*, o sea un conjunto de datos limitado que se usa como un buffer para agilisar tareas de replicación.

Por lo general esto añade alrededor de 5% al volumen de tus datos.

**El registro**

La carpeta de datos contiene todos los archivos de registro (*journal files*) que almacenan cambios en disco antes de aplicarlo a la base de datos.

**Registros vacios**

MongoDB mantiene una lista de registros vacios mientras borra documentos y colecciones. Se puede re-usar este espacio, pero es no es el comportamiento por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de que [motor de almacenamiento](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/storage-engines/index.html) (storage engine) estés usando.

Por default, desde mongoDB versión 3.2, el motor de almacenamiento es Wired Tiger, que en general es utiliza menos espacio porque [comprime](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression) los datos antes de escribirlos en disco. Anteriormente es MMAPV1.

Estos son solo los defaults. La configuración se encuentra en el archivo *mongod.conf*, que comunmente se encuentra en el directorio */etc*. Busca la sección *storage* para ver que motor estás usando:

`storage:
   engine: mmapv1`

o

`storage:
   engine: wiredTiger`

Si estás usando MMAPV1, lo mas conveniente es exportar la base de datos usando mongodump y cambiar la configuracion a WiredTiger editando *mongod.conf*. Una vez hecho esto, restaurar usando mongorestore.